# getting error mno-fused-madd installing kivy in virtualenv over fish shell

Tags: xcode5, clang, llvm, osx-mavericks, kivy

Hi I am getting the error saying `clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd'` when I am trying to install **[kivy](http://kivy.org)** in `virtualenv` named **kivyprogramming**.

```
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future -pipe -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c /private/tmp/pip-build-UDRH26/kivy/kivy/graphics/texture.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/private/tmp/pip-build-UDRH26/kivy/kivy/graphics/texture.o -F/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks -arch x86_64

    clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd'

     error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

even though I tried using : `sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install kivy` got the same error above `clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd'`

my gcc version:

```
$gcc --version 
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

Also got error compiling cython file

```
cythoning /private/var/folders/43/m1qv9zf53q19sqh6h9kg9pz80000gn/T/pip-build-Im9flX/kivy/kivy/graphics/texture.pyx to /private/var/folders/43/m1qv9zf53q19sqh6h9kg9pz80000gn/T/pip-build-Im9flX/kivy/kivy/graphics/texture.c

     Error compiling Cython file:
     ------------------------------------------------------------
     ...
         cpdef release(self)
         cpdef get_pixel_color(self, int wx, int wy)
         cdef void create_fbo(self)
         cdef void delete_fbo(self)
         cdef void apply(self)
                       ^
     ------------------------------------------------------------

     kivy/graphics/fbo.pxd:25:19: Signature not compatible with previous declaration

     Error compiling Cython file:
     ------------------------------------------------------------
     ...
         cdef void push_states(self, list names) except *
         cdef void pop_state(self, str name) except *
         cdef void pop_states(self, list names) except *
         cdef void enter(self) except *
         cdef void leave(self) except *
         cdef void apply(self) except *
                       ^
     ------------------------------------------------------------
```

Should I continue using [fish shell](http://fishshell.com) as default shell for baking cake of kivy or do I have to switch back to `bash` shell that is default in my OSx mavericks ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by an apparent bug in cython 0.22, which we haven't resolved in kivy master yet (it's not clear what's best, or whether we should fix part of the problem in cython itself). You can resolve it by using cython 0.21, or alternatively there's a pull request for a fix in kivy's github repository that you can try if you're willing to build the source manually.

I don't think it has anything to do with your using fish, that's probably just a coincidence with the cython update.

Comment: maybe you are right but I figured out the solution to get in installed. the problem came when I installed OSx Mavericks commandline tools, so all I have to is to add the following line in my `~/.bashrc` i.e. `export ARCHFLAGS="-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future"` and then I already had latest kivy cloned from github I went into that directory and ran `python setup.py install` and it the above error message only appeared as warning message but installation went successful. This technique didn't worked when I tried doing `make install` since you also provide makefile.